# A multiplication table with proper formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiplication, tabular

```
table = []

row_one = int(input("Enter row number:"))

column = int(input("Enter column number:"))

for j in range(1, row_one + 1):

    for i in range(1, column + 1):
        temp = []
        temp.append(j * i)
        table.append(temp)
print table
```

If my row and column are 2 by 2, respectively.
my output looks like:

```
[[1], [2], [2], [4]]
```

However, it should actually look like:

```
1 2
2 4
```

Comment: I suggest making some kind of effort to make it look the way you want it to.

Comment: so make it the way you like it!

Comment: what do you want once you get to double digits, should it all be formatted evenly?

Comment: Well, have you tried iterating over the array and printing it the way you want it?

Comment: self promotion:  answer to [how-do-i-write-a-function-to-ouput-a-multiplication-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50050155/7505395) its not the same kind of multiplication table, but you can get an idea about formatting output

Comment: Use the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method to create strings to output.

Answer (score 1):

I'd move `temp=[]` outside of the inner loop and `table.append(temp)` outside of the inner loop too. So table will look like: `[[1,2],[2,4]]`. I also track the longest value so I know how much space to pad it in the table. I cast the value to a string because it looks like it's just for output, but this can be done later if you need to reference the table values.

```
table = []

row_one = int(input("Enter row number:"))

column = int(input("Enter column number:"))
biggest=1
for j in range(1, row_one + 1):
    temp=[]
    for i in range(1, column + 1):
        v=str(i*j)
        temp.append(v)
        if len(v)>biggest:
           biggest=len(v)
    table.append(temp)

for row in table:
  t=[n+' '*(biggest-len(n)) for n in row]
  print ' '.join(t)
```

Output(with 2,2 input)

```
1 2
2 4
```

Output(with 5,5 input-to show padding)

```
1  2  3  4  5 
2  4  6  8  10
3  6  9  12 15
4  8  12 16 20
5  10 15 20 25
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do exactly what you want. Dynamic for different matrix sizes too

```
table = []

row_one = int(input("Enter row number:"))

column = int(input("Enter column number:"))

for j in range(row_one):
    table.append([])
    for i in range(column):
        table[j].append((j+1) * (i+1))

for row in table:
    for column in row:
        if column != row[len(row) - 1]:
            print column,
        else:
            print column
```

Output:

```
Enter row number:2
Enter column number:2
1 2
2 4
```

Comment: what happens if table has more than 2 rows? where did the user input go?

Comment: Changed it to be dynamic

Comment: Your output is wrong, it should be a 4 not 3 you need `((j+1) * (i+1))`

Comment: Fail forgot about PEMDAS

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
table = []

row_one = int(input("Enter row number:"))

column = int(input("Enter column number:"))

for j in range(1, row_one + 1):

   for i in range(1, column + 1):
        temp = []
        temp.append(j * i)
        table.append(temp)
print (np.reshape(table, (row_one, column)))
```

Output:

```
[[1 2]
[2 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print with the `print_function` using `sep='\n'`. You could remove the `[`,`]` with some formatting, but the main idea is here. I also fix a little error, look at the comment:

```
from __future__ import print_function

table = []

row_one = int(input("Enter row number:"))

column = int(input("Enter column number:"))

for j in range(1, row_one + 1):
    temp = []  # temp need to be outside of the loop to work as intended
    for i in range(1, column + 1):
        temp.append(j * i)

    table.append(temp)  # note the identation of this


print(*table, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Enter row number:4
Enter column number:4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[3, 6, 9, 12]
[4, 8, 12, 16]
```

Bonus: the necessary python one-liners

```
table = [[(j+1) * (i+1) for i in range(column)] for j in range(row_one)]
print(*(' '.join(map(str,line)) for line in table), sep='\n')
```